# How boost.asio discover which port is my server app listening on?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

it is a little bit strange to me that boost.asio doesn`t use basic concept when client app connecting to the server - using IP address and port. May be I am a little bit noobie in Boost - and I accept that - but anyway I do not understand.
So, I have code like this to get client connected to the server on the localhost:

```
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        tcp::resolver::query query("localhost", "daytime"); 
        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query); 
        tcp::resolver::iterator end;

        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
        while(error && endpoint_iterator != end) {
            socket.close();
            socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
        }
```

Windows in its WinSock 2.0 uses two parameters - IP and port - to identify the server. 
So, the qurestion is - how exactly Asio finds out which port is server listening to connections on? Does it scans all ports? And, if it does, what will happen if two servers listening on different ports at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are telling it that you want to connect to localhost on the port used by the daytime service. It will look up the appropriate port number in the services file (usually C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\services under Windows, I believe /etc/services under Unix). You could also use an explicit port number there.

Comment: I didn`t quite understand what the second parameter means in query ctor. the first one is IP address I want to connect to, right? and what does the second mean?

Comment: The second parameter is either a port number or the name of a service. If it is a service name, asio will look it up in the services file to find the appropriate port number for that service. Take a look at the services file with a text editor and you will see how it works.

Comment: ok, then how can I start a server on a port I need? code for that on server side is:
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13));

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. That code starts a server listening on port 13 (daytime service) already.

Comment: daytime actually is windows service that is using port 13 even though our server is not running. The server is set to use port 13 and the client is obtain the port 13 by checking the port of daytime service from file services. That why when you change the server to other port, the client cannot establish the connection.

Answer (score 8):

Try,

```
tcp::resolver::query query("localhost", boost::lexical_cast<string>(port));//assuming port is an int
```

To answer your question, recall that you are starting the server on port 13. This happens to be the port which runs the Linux daytime service [(http://www.sorgonet.com/linux/linuxdaemons/)](http://www.sorgonet.com/linux/linuxdaemons/). Hence, they are subsequently able to use query("localhost","daytime") rather than specifying the port.

Answer (score 0):

open netcat listen on port 13 on the localhost
it will accept the demo's connection. type some blabla when it connects and you'll see the output on the demo program
to run the netcat, run:
nc -l -p 13

windows? no netcat? install cygwin, and add netcat